# How to move GlobalSuppressions.cs (Suppress Code Analysis) from project root in special folder?

Tags: visual-studio, static-analysis

I would like to move GlobalSuppressions.cs (Suppress Code Analysis) from project root in special folder.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cORYO.png)

I would like to use one GlobalSuppressions.cs file in several projects of one solutions.

Comment: If I were you, I'd mention the IDE you are using (Visual Studio) in the tags section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to move it. If you do, it simple recreates the file in the root folder. If you wanted to share the file, then you could:

1. Right-click on the other project
2. Click Add Existing Item
3. Locate the GlobalSuppressions.cs file and select it (single-click only)
4. Click the down-arrow just to the right of the Add button
5. Select Add As Link

This will basically add a shortcut to the file in your other project. You can tell if it has worked because the file icon in Solution Explorer will have a little blue arrow and square.